# How do I package code within VSCode with Raylib

Tags: c++, build, package, raylib

I have made a game using C++ code within VSCode using raylib libraries and the raylib compiler. I want to know how the package/build the game into an application so I can play it without having to run the code over and over again. Does anyone know how I would do this

Comment: You could use NSIS to create an installer and properly install your game in `c:\Program Files`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.